# GhostDoc - Updating derived class comments

Tags: interface, comments, derived-class, xml-comments, ghostdoc

I have an interface (`ISomeInterface`) with full xml comments, and some derived classes with matching xml comments.

If I change the comment in the interface, is it possible to update the comments in all derived classes with GhostDoc (or any other tool)?

I appreciate this may cause unwanted changes in some scenarios but I'm not concerned about that in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Re-Document command of the GhostDoc v4.0 Beta - it will recreate XML documentation while preserve your custom tags.

Let me know if this helps.

Thanks!